# ASP.NET MVC - some threads not hitting HttpModule

Tags: asp.net-mvc, multithreading, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, httpmodule

I have an MVC web-application that shares some common code with another application (non-web).

One of the things both applications have to do is to connect to a specific data-store.  The non-web application runs multiple threads each with a different set of connection parameters, and so the common code has each connection marked as "thread static".  This connection therefore has to be thread-static for my ASP.NET MVC application too.

In my web application, I use an `HttpModule`.  The `context_BeginRequest` opens the connection and the `begin_EndRequest` closes the connection.  (The connection is automatically closed by the datastore after 30 seconds, so I can't keep it open indefinitely).

My web application seems to work perfectly well, except that occasionly it throws an error saying that it can't use the connection.

I investigated this by adding logging.  I logged each thread as it hit the `context_BeginRequest`, the `context_EndRequest` and when it throws the exception.  I discovered that the error is thrown by a thread in my application that has never hit the `HttpModule's context_BeginRequest`.  Because it didn't hit that, no connection was opened.

My understanding was that the thread should have hit the `HttpModule` - so why isn't it?

If I can't guarantee this behaviour, then what approach would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to using Async Code somewhere in the application.

Async code uses a callback mechanism which is not guaranteed to run on the same thread as the code which called it.

You could pass the thread synchronization context, or simply the connection itself as a parameter into the Async function

Comment: This isn't an answer. It should be a comment.